# How prove that $6x - 6 < (1 + 4 \sqrt{x} + x) \log x$

Tags: inequality

How prove that $6x - 6 < (1 + 4 \sqrt{x} + x) \log x$ for $x>1$

---

$((1 + 4 \sqrt{x} + x) \log x)'=\textstyle 1 + 4 x^{-1/2} + x^{-1} + (2 x^{-1/2} + 1) \log (x)$

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=(1+4\sqrt x+x)\log x-(6x-6)$. Then, we have
$$f'(x)=\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt x}+1\right)\log x+\frac{1+4\sqrt x+x}{x}-6$$
$$f''(x)=\frac{x-\sqrt x\ \log x-1}{x^2}$$
Let $g(x)=x-\sqrt x\ \log x-1$. Then, we have
$$g'(x)=\frac{-2-\log x+2\sqrt x}{2\sqrt x},\quad g''(x)=\frac{\log x}{4x^{3/2}}$$

Now note that $g''(x)\gt 0$ for $x\gt 1$ and that $g'(1)=g(1)=f'(1)=f(1)=0$.

From these, you should be able to prove that $f(x)\gt 0$ for $x\gt 1$.